# How can I add a SSL certificate on my apk?

Tags: android, https, android-webview

I am trying to make a connection to an `https` url.

The problem that I am facing is that when I am trying to connect via `WebView` I am getting the following error:

> Failed to validate the certificate chain, error: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.

I have searched a lot but most of the responses about this error is to ignore the error and let the url goes without problems.

It seems that if I add the certificate on my Android phone it works well but it does have any sense that I would have to add the certificate of SSL in each device I want to install de app (because they will be third party clients).

Because of this, I have thought about add the certificate into the apk so the users of the application will not have errors with that certificate and they will be able to connect to that `https` url.

Is it possible to add SSL certificate on the apk?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl.html

Comment: @DonChakkappan I looked at this but the certificate have to be on the mobile phone or in the apk? Because of this line: `InputStream caInput = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("load-der.crt"));` I guess that it is retrieving the certificate from local device.

Comment: keep your certificate in assets folder & open it like context.getAssets().open("aliasname.cer")

Comment: @DonChakkappan And when I add it on assets folder, what file type should I use to add the certificate?

Answer (score 3):

It will be very easy to setup & learn SSL if you go with a local server.

1 ] Setup a Server (For Eg; TomCat) for SSL communications (https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/ssl-howto.html).

2 ] Write a simple Web-Service (http://www.radcortez.com/ssl-tls-rest-server-client-with-spring-and-tomee/).

3 ] Prepare a self -signed certificate using any one of the tool (Keytool , OpenSSL etc)

4 ] It is adviced to use commands to create keystore,certificate etc.But for the lazy people there is a GUI based program :) (http://keystore-explorer.org/downloads.html)

5 ] Now ,It's time to pin SSL certificate to Android Applications.Add your aliasname.cer (It can export from s/w mentioned in point [4])

6 ] Check host name programatically (https://infinum.co/the-capsized-eight/securing-mobile-banking-on-android-with-ssl-certificate-pinning).

7 ] Create a custom Trust Manager,So that we , can omit android system's default Trust Manager (https://github.com/ikust/hello-pinnedcerts)

Comment: Can you clarify point 5? "Add your .cer", to where? Thanks