# Xamarin PCL self signed certificat for Android and IOS

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, ssl-certificate, cross-platform

I'm trying to pass my full Rest service from http to https.

I created a self-signed certificate, I had it to IIS Express. I validate it on google Chrome and it work perfectly fine with postman. My rest service work in http and https.

I use a PCL project (IOS and Android) everything is working fine with http request but I have exception with https request. the exception message is null.

I tried to create a test certificate directly from Visual Studio 2015 but the button is disabled in properties ->Signing.

I also tried to install my self-signed certificate as a Trusted Root but no success for the communication between my simulator and my rest Service.

my code

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    private string url = string.Empty;
    private HttpClient _client;


    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        switch (Device.RuntimePlatform)
        {
            case Device.iOS:
                _client = new HttpClient(new NSUrlSessionHandler());
                break;
            case Device.Android:
                _client = new HttpClient();
                break;
        }
        _client = new HttpClient();
        test();


    }

    private async void test()
    {
        //url = "http://192.168.1.106:9630/PrototypeB.svc/Test";
        url = "https://192.168.1.106:44301/PrototypeB.svc/Test";
        try
        {
            var _content = await _client.GetStringAsync(url);
            List<Test> _posts = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Test>>(_content);
        }
        catch (HttpRequestException e)
        {
            string test = e.Message;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            string test = e.Message;
        }
    }
}
```

How can I  communicate with my Android and IOS Simulator with https and self-signed certificate?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45856383/how-can-i-add-a-ssl-certificate-on-my-apk/45875458#45875458

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can use **[ServicePointManager](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/System.Net.ServicePointManager/)** to ignore the certificate validation check.

Execute the code in your iOS and Android platforms like this:

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (se, cert, chain, sslerror) => { 
                         return true; 
                     };
```

References:

- [Untrusted HTTPS
  certificate](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/53937/untrusted-https-certificate)
- [HTTPS ignore
  certificate](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/69210/https-ignore-certificate)
- [Ignore SSL certificate errors in Xamarin.Forms (PCL)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28629989/ignore-ssl-certificate-errors-in-xamarin-forms-pcl)
- [SSL Validation in
  PCL](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/24289/ssl-validation-in-pcl)

*Also, [ModernHttpClient Pro](https://components.xamarin.com/view/modernhttpclient-pro) provide this feature, but it is not free.*

Comment: What about UWP? I would like to be able to get this to work on UWP also.